# friend request SQL statement OR Operator not working

Tags: php

Good day
I'm trying to add a friend request functionality but this statement can't work
am trying to create ignore or cancel friend request functionality, this function should work for Ignore and cancel friend request but it does not working

I tried to create two function in a vise versa way like i will show below.

I tryed this but didn't work

```php
this is a model
   public function cancel_or_ignore_friend_request($data){
     $this->db->query('DELETE FROM friend_request WHERE (sender = :my_id AND receiver = :frnd_id) || (sender = :frnd_id AND receiver = :my_id)');
     $this->db->bind(':my_id', $data['my_id']);
     $this->db->bind(':frnd_id', $data['user_id']);

     if($this->db->execute()){
       return true;
     }else {
       return false;
     }
   }

   public function cancel_or_ignore($data){
     $this->db->query('DELETE FROM friend_request WHERE sender = :my_id AND receiver = :frnd_id');
     $this->db->bind(':my_id', $data['my_id']);
     $this->db->bind(':frnd_id', $data['user_id']);

     if($this->db->execute()){
       return true;
     }else {
       return false;
     }
   }
```

Then i used these two functions like this:

```php
this is a controller
  public function cancelFriendRequest(){
      if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $data = [
          'my_id' => trim($_SESSION['user_id']),
          'user_id' => trim($_POST['some_id']),
        ];
//focus on this if statement
          if ($this->userModel->cancel_or_ignore_friend_request($data) || $this->userModel->cancel_or_ignore($data)) {
            echo json_encode(1);
          }else {
            echo json_encode(0);
          }

      }else {
        redirect('profile?u='.$_SESSION['username']);
      }
    }
```

It should be like this and work

```php
this is a model
// CANCLE FRIEND REQUEST
   public function cancel_or_ignore_friend_request($data){
     $this->db->query('DELETE FROM friend_request WHERE (sender = :my_id AND receiver = :frnd_id) OR (sender = :frnd_id AND receiver = :my_id)');
     $this->db->bind(':my_id', $data['my_id']);
     $this->db->bind(':frnd_id', $data['user_id']);

     if($this->db->execute()){
       return true;
     }else {
       return false;
     }
   }
```

I used this one like this on my controller

```php
this is a controller
  public function cancelFriendRequest(){
      if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $data = [
          'my_id' => trim($_SESSION['user_id']),
          'user_id' => trim($_POST['some_id']),
        ];

          if ($this->userModel->cancel_or_ignore_friend_request($data)) {
            echo json_encode(1);
          }else {
            echo json_encode(0);
          }

      }else {
        redirect('profile?u='.$_SESSION['username']);
      }
    }
```

Comment: In what way isn't it working? Is it returning `false`? Or is it returning `true` but not deleting anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem might be that you are using the `:my_id` and `:frnd_id` parameters twice. This can work but it depends upon a parameter setting. Instead use unique parameter names, however you can reuse the actual data values as many times as you like.

```
$this->db->query('DELETE FROM friend_request 
                    WHERE (     sender = :my_id AND receiver = :frnd_id 
                            OR  sender = :frnd_id2 AND receiver = :my_id2
                          )';
$this->db->bind(':my_id',  $data['my_id']);
$this->db->bind(':my_id2', $data['my_id']);

$this->db->bind(':frnd_id',  $data['user_id']);
$this->db->bind(':frnd_id2', $data['user_id']);
```